# undefined method `new_record?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Estoy usando la gema Cocoon y me da el siguiente error

> undefined method `new_record?' for nil:NilClass

la situación es la siguiente. Tengo un Evento (**event**) el cual tiene muchos usuarios (**user**) y para relacionarlos tengo el modelo **events_user**.

event.rb

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :type_event
    belongs_to :contact
    has_many :events_user
    has_many :users, through: :events_user
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :events_user, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :events_user
  has_many :events, through: :events_user
end
```

events_user.rb

```
class EventsUser < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :event
    belongs_to :user
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
....
<hr>
      <!-- render users -->
      <div class="users">
        <%= form.fields_for :events_users do |user| %>
          <%= render 'user_fields', f: user %>
        <%end%>
        <%= link_to_add_association "+", form, :users, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      </div>

....
```

_user_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="form-row nested-fields">

    <div class="form-group col">
      <%= f.label :user_id, "Usuario" %>
      <%= f.collection_select(:user_id, User.all, :id, :name, {prompt: 'Selecciona un usuario'}, {class: "form-control"}) %>  
    </div>  

    <div class="form-group col">
      <%= f.label :estatus, "estatus" %>
      <%= f.select(:estatus, [['Notificado', 'Notificado'], ['Aceptado', 'Aceptado'], ['Rechazado', 'Rechazado']], {}, {class: "form-control"}) %>
    </div> 

    <div class="form-group col">
      <%= link_to_remove_association "-", f, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
    </div>

</div>
```

Lo que busco es insertar en la Join table (**evets_user**) pues tengo más campos además del evento y el usuario. cabe mencionar que los usuarios ya están previamente capturados

UPDATE

Log

> Started GET "/events/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-21 08:58:49 -0600
>   Processing by EventsController#new as HTML   [1m[36mUser Load
>   (1.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE
>   `users`.`id` = 1 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1[0m   Rendering
>   events/new.html.erb within layouts/application   [1m[36mTypeEvent
>   Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT `type_events`.* FROM
>   `type_events`[0m   [1m[36mContact Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT
>   `contacts`.* FROM `contacts`[0m   [1m[36mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m 
>   [1m[34mSELECT `users`.* FROM `users`[0m   Rendered
>   events/_user_fields.html.erb (142.0ms)   Rendered
>   events/_form.html.erb (202.0ms)   Rendered events/new.html.erb within
>   layouts/application (249.0ms) Completed 500 Internal Server Error in
>   552ms (ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
>
> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `new_record?' for
>   nil:NilClass):
>       11:     </div> 
>       12: 
>       13:     <div class="form-group col">
>       14:       <%= link_to_remove_association "-", f, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
>       15:     </div>
>       16:
>
>       17: </div>    app/views/events/_user_fields.html.erb:14:in`_app_views_events__user_fields_html_erb___944412905_33020580'
>   app/views/events/_form.html.erb:51:in `block (2 levels) in
>   _app_views_events__form_html_erb___697732379_39894120' app/views/events/_form.html.erb:50:in`block in
>   _app_views_events__form_html_erb___697732379_39894120' app/views/events/_form.html.erb:3:in
>   `_app_views_events__form_html_erb___697732379_39894120'
>   app/views/events/new.html.erb:7:in`
>   _app_views_events_new_html_erb__778975198_40105848'

Comment: ¿donde te muestra `undefined method 'new_record?' for nil:NilClass`? Agrega el log del error

Comment: Ya agregue el log

Answer (score 0):

Creo q debes de ensayar creando una instancia del objeto q necesitas sea renderizado así no debería generarse ningún tipo de error , algo como EventUser.new or EventUsert.build